# Self message return value in UML

Tags: uml

I want to show that a self message will return an error in UML. I don't think that this is possible, but how else I could accomplish this ?

I am using Enterprise Arthitect.

Thanks.

Comment: In what kind of diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible... Self messages have no return message, therefore there is no place to put the error.